# Would multithreading help a Fast Fourier Transform?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to get performance out of an application by multi-threading it for a project. So far I attempted to make a Task that would be created to handle a 2048 segment of audio, and that task would be created for each segment to run independently. However, this configuration means making several thousands of tasks which causes more performance problems then worth, not to mention I couldn't find a way to convert the existing recursive FFT into an iterative one to maintain that 1:1 on segments to tasks.
Would there be any benefit to continuing to attempt this? or should I look more to optimizing the application else where.

Comment: I would bet if FFT can be multithreaded there is a nuget package out there that does that.

Comment: BTW: You wouldn't use a fixed relation segment <=> task but create a pool of workers that continously take the next todo from a list and handle it.

Comment: "performance out of an application by multi-threading" - You should first make sure the existing code is as fast as it can be. If you write code without thinking of performance, it will likely be *magnitudes* slower than it has to be. FFT is a common algorithm, so there are highly optimized libraries for it. Take a look at Math.Net or intel performance primitives, if you wrote your FFT yourself I would guess that one of these would be significantly faster.

Comment: @Klamsi so essentially Queue each 2048 segment and allow the tasks/threads to pull the oldest available, process it, then place it into a common output, if I understand you right

Comment: @JonasH will do, and no I didn't write any of the code myself which is why I'm struggling to solve the problem

Comment: @ThomasPeters Yes, but don't forget a multithreading ready List. e.g. somthing from `System.Collections.Concurrent` or lock it on every access.

Comment: @Klamsi So I wrote that up and it functions, however I'm getting 2.5 to 2.7s runs regardless of the number of workers (sequentially its 2 to 2.1) I would assume that means the transform is the limitation, but I find it strange the time frame is the same when I can see the threads each running the transform independently. so I'm not exactly sure why

Comment: Run it without multi threading and look at the CPU usage. If it is near 100% there is no benefit in multi threading. As I said, maybe your FFT already uses threads internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with Klamsi's solution (commented on the question). After doing more cleaning and bug fixing, I settled on a data structure that would be Queued that includes the data's respective index in an output array to avoid to results being in the wrong order.
The result after this (with output locking):
Debug Sequential: 2.1ms
Debug Multithread: 2.6ms
Release Sequential: ~940ms
Release Multithread: ~650ms

release multithread can hit around 500-600 without locking.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your core usage on your computer when running the transformation as a serial process. Have you maxed out your CPU?
If not, then the parallel library can help you access more computing power.

I would recommend reading up on tutorials and theory on the parallel library (assembly) in C#.

Comment: I'm familiar with TPL, I'm also aware I can get more performance, my problem lies with the method of doing so and if it will actually provide a benefit. I only ask because I haven't seen a way to do it iteratively nor have I seen any multithreaded implementations

Comment: Well considering that each point in your "original" source input, can be "calculated" is that the right word? without the need to access the results of any prior "calculations"
I don't see why you COULDN'T increase your performance on multiple cores. 

If you are working on single core, the benefit might be much smaller than expected, but as long as you are on a multi-core PC, there should be significant gains to doing the processing in parallel. 

If you use the parallel library, the code will organise the tasks for you, in an attempt to use your hardware more effiently

Comment: however, significant gains, do matter, if your algorithm of calculation isn't efficient, then the gains will likely not match up to expectations. 

Assuming you have a N size of calculations, and N is NOT infinite. Then you have a change to complete your tasks. However, if the N set is extremely large, then despite having efficient algorithms and parallel processing, you might not complete your calculations in an expected time. 

2048 segment however, be fine.

Comment: Run a single sample calculation, record the time. (or a small set in serial, and calculate the average time)
Then parallel.foreach(), all 2048 calculations -> (they will all finish slightly slower than the original times) but the total run time, should now be totaltime/core -> in an ideal setup. (however, this won't happen, because your inability to consome all cores CPU for all tasks.)

Comment: So yes, a multicore system, will make the total runtime quicker. 

If you can't make an implementation work, then show us your work, and we can point to where you are having issues. But don't expect people where to do your work for you.

Comment: This all assumes you are going to try to do the FFT with a discrete method.